# Is there a formal definition of what a significant figure really is?

Tags: measurements, error-analysis

What does it mean, formally, when we say that a digit in a number is a [significant figure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures)?

Comment: It generally means ignoring the lower order digits in a number that resolves to too great a detail given the approximations in a calculation, or also in an experiment, the estimated errors.

Comment: More on [significant figures](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+%5Berror-analysis%5D+significant+figure*).